# Plot intensity profile of a reduced (Core.reduce) image - Android(java)

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, plot

I have used OpenCV function Core.reduce() to sum the pixels of my image over the x and y coords.

```
Mat img = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, img); // my image

Mat col_sum = new Mat();
Mat row_sum = new Mat();
Core.reduce(img, col_sum, 1, Core.REDUCE_SUM, -1);
Core.reduce(img, row_sum, 1, Core.REDUCE_SUM, -1);
```

Now I want to retrieve the output vector and plot the summed up intensity of the pixels I(x) along y. Do you have any idea on how I could proceed? Is it possible to do it using Android GraphView? 
I am new in programming so any comment/answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: not sure if it's available for Java, but OpenCV has a module for 2d plots from a vector https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/186

Comment: Thanks for your comment, apparently the 2d plots module (OpenCV) is now available for java but not for android yet.Thanks again!